# MVC5 EF6 Update Model From Database Breaks Foreign Key Relationships In Random Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC5/EF6 web application using a SQL Server 2012 back-end. The database is a standard relational database. In Visual Studio (2103) I segregated the models into the type and relations - for example a customer model, contains the customer, address and province  table etc, the orders model contains order header, order items, products etc. Note that orders model does contain some customer tables due to a different issue and vice versa.

My problem is, if I add a new field to any table (either parent, child or standalone table) either as foreign key or simple type (varchar/int) as soon as I use the update model from database, Visual Studio throws masses of errors on foreign keys that are totally unrelated. For example I added a client middle name varchar field to client yet the foreign key links on the order header to order items break, with VS complaining they could not be loaded/are not valid.

The only way I have been able to fix this (based on a previous stackoverflow article) is starting from the first model, execute the "Run Custom Tool" on the TT and context files (in that order) on all models. This sometimes works first time or requires multiple tries to remove the errors.

Could anybody help by telling me what is it I am doing wrong? My knowledge is based on a number of Microsoft tutorials and everything was working fine until one day it just started with this behaviour.

Thank you!

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a very frustrating two weeks the only way I was able to solve this was to add all tables that have any form of relationship to all models - feels wrong, looks wrong but was the only way I could get the errors to go away as any standalone models did not have this issue.

Cheers

David

Comment: I had problems using table splitting in EF6. I could get code migration to accept the splitting with careful attributing my models, but I could not update the models separately. I followed all the examples I could find, but it just kept complaining. Split tables uses foreign keys, so I thought it might be related to what you experiences. Something may be broken in EF6.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback Anders! I will definitely look into it!